# Two similar types of questions of double integral involving max operator.

Tags: integration

I have come across two questions of similar type and am struggling to deal with them.

$$1.\;\;\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}e^{max(x^{2},y^{2})}dxdy$$

$$2. \;\;\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\cos(max(x^{3},y^{\frac{3}{2}}))dxdy$$

I asked the first question on this site a few months ago but the answerer didn't  explain how he did particular steps. So please help me solve one with proper justification and I will do the other on my own. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first integral, break up the region to deal with the max. Namely,
$x^2\geq y^2$ if and only if $x\geq y$ in this region. So, you may integrate over the two regions separately, 
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^xe^{x^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx+
\int_0^1\int_0^ye^{y^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy
$$
which you can tackle by u substitution after integrating in the first variable.

Similarly, 
breaking up the region we have 
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2}\cos(x^3)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx+\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{y}}\cos(y^{3/2})\mathrm dx\mathrm dy
$$
both also easy to tackle with u substitution after integrating in the first variable.

Answer (score 1):

Break the region in to one region where $e^{max(x^2,y^2)} = e^{x^2}$ and one where $e^{max(x^2,y^2)} = e^{y^2}$

[image]

$\int_0^{1} \int_0^1 e^{max(x^2,y^2)} \ dy\ dx = \int_0^{1} \int_0^x e^{x^2} \ dy\ dx + \int_0^{1} \int_0^y e^{y^2} \ dx\ dy = 2\int_0^{1} \int_0^y e^{y^2} \ dx\ dy$

Answer (score 0):

Since this integral involves "max($x^2,y^2$)", we need to separate the region of integration into a region where $x^2> y^2$ and a region where $y^2> x^2$.  The integrals with respect to x and y are from 0 to 1, look at the square, on an xy- coordinate system, with vertices (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), and (1,1).  $y^2= x^2$ is the same as $y^2- x^2= (x- y)(x+ y)= 0$.  Since x+ y is never 0 on that square, we must have $x- y= 0$ or $y= x$, the diagonal line from (0,0) to (1,1). $y> x$, so $y^2> x^2$ on the triangle with vertices (0,0), (0,1), and (1,1).  $x> y$, so $x^2> y^2$ on the triangle with vertices (0,0), (1,0), and (1,1).

So $\int_0^1 e^{max(x^2,y^2)}dydx= \int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^x e^{x^2}dydx+ \int_{x=0}^1\int_x^1 e^{y^2} dydx$.